# Can I restrict a process' access to the filesystem using `systemd-run --user`?

Tags: permissions, systemd, rsync, container

I am looking for a way to run a process with limited privileges and limited access to the filesystem.  I was hoping to use `systemd-run` to do this, which works perfectly when run as root:

```
$ sudo systemd-run --pipe --quiet --wait -p ReadOnlyPaths=/ touch ~/nope
/usr/bin/touch: cannot touch '/home/me/nope': Read-only file system
```

Unfortunately, the same options don't seem to work in `--user` mode:

```
$ systemd-run --user --pipe --quiet --wait -p ReadOnlyPaths=/ touch ~/nope
$ ls -al ~/nope
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 0 Nov  9 13:51 /home/me/nope
```

**As a non-root (non-sudo) user, can I use `systemd-run` to run a process with limited privileges, limited access to the file system, etc.?  If so, how?**

---

Notes:

- I saw mentions online of needing unprivileged user namespaces for systemd features like `ProtectHome`, but on my machine `sysctl` does say `kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone = 1`, so this does not seem to be the issue?
- Some background in case of a frame challenge: Currently I have a line that says `command="rsync --server --daemon ." … ssh-rsa …` in `.ssh/authorized_keys`, which restricts logins using a specific key to running only `rsync --server --daemon`, as documented in "[Using rsync daemon features via a remote-shell connection](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html#USING_RSYNC-DAEMON_FEATURES_VIA_A_REMOTE-SHELL_CONNECTION)".  If possible, I would like to restrict the resulting `rsync` process on the server to only be able to modify certain folders.

  I realize that there are other ways to achieve this specifically for rsync, but I'm interested in a general answer about `systemd-run`'s features.